# how to instal ubuntu 19.10 alogside windows 10 (installed on legacy mode)?

Tags: dual-boot, windows, 19.10

I am trying to instal Ubuntu 19.10 on my hp computer alongside Windows 10 (version 18362) using a 16 Gb usb stick and rufus but i faced a problem during the instalation when Ubuntu detects Windows 10 but doesn't give the option to intal alongside Windows it just says to erase the disk and instal Ubuntu. then i cheked and found that my Windows is installed on legacy mode. so how do i instal Ubuntu on legacy mode or can i change Windows to EUFI ?

Comment: Ubuntu installer will auto-detect the right mode - BIOS/UEFI, and install accordingly.  The reason you don't get an option to install alongside Windows is probably because there are 4 primary partitions. You'll need to check if that is the case.

Comment: Ensure you are booting the installer in legacy mode by checking the BIOS/UEFI Settings. How it boots is how it installs. Some settings allow both boot modes, with you selecting a preference if both are present.  In that case, select legacy before UEFI to match your legacy Windows installation.

Comment: first ,how to reduce the number of partitions (i have 4 partitions C:,D:,recovery and for the système)?